# My data won't save to SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Why won't my data make it to my sql database? I know that I am connected to the database. And I know that the posted data is arriving at this page because I can echo it. There is something wrong with the line with the !emptys. When I enter a value for yyy but not xxx I get the "Please Fill out all Fields" message. But if I leave both blank, or enter a value for only xxx, I get nothing. And when I enter values for both, I do get the "Failed" message so the data is not being inserted into the sql.

```
if (isset($_POST['xxx']) && ($_POST['yyy']))  {
$xxx = $_POST['xxx'];
$age = $_POST['yyy'];
    if (!empty($xxx) && !empty($yyy)) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($child_name)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."')";
        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        echo 'Data inserted.';
        } else {
            echo 'Failed.';
        }
} else {
    echo 'Please fill out all fields';
}
}
```

Comment: ...and move yourself upwards one step to use either `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: you can check `empty($_POST[])` it will check if its setted first of all

Answer (score 3):

First correct your `isset` statement for `yyy`

```
if (isset($_POST['xxx']) && isset($_POST['yyy']))
```

Second correction :

`$yyy = $_POST['yyy'];` instead of `$age = $_POST['yyy'];`

Third correction :

`if (mysql_query($query))` instead of `if ($query_run = mysql_query($query))`

Because `mysql_query()` returns `bool`

`echo mysql_error();` Instead of `echo 'Failed.';`  to get your mysql error !

Comment: Thank you, figured it out. Had to leave a blank for auto incremented column.

Comment: @user1753464 you're welcome, an answer validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your php and mysql errors.

```
<?php

echo (mysql_error());
error_report(E_ALL);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check query and try this code and rename this on your `('id', 'field name')`:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO test ('id', 'field name') VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($child_name) ."', '". mysql_real_escape_string($age) ."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the query manualy?

Echo the query before sending it and try to run it in phpmyadmin

also add `echo mysql_error();` to view the error

Answer (score 0):

few issues:

```
1.  if (isset($_POST['xxx']) && ($_POST['yyy']))  { //needs to be
    if (isset($_POST['xxx']) || isset($_POST['yyy']))  {

2.  if (!empty($xxx) && !empty($yyy)) { //needs to be
    if ( !empty($xxx)) ||  !empty($age) ) { 

3.  if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) { //whats $query_run?
```

`mysql_query($query)` returns a `TRUE` if the query is successful. Refer [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)